# Searching for a matching string

Tags: python

I am trying to search a list of strings for a match.

This is my list of strings:

```
ignore = ['40015','8002']
```

and I am using the following to look for a match

```
if any(evtsummary in s for s in ignore):
```

if evtsummary = "something 8002" it matches

if evtsummary = "something8002" it does not match

I want it to match in both cases.

Comment: You're missing the part where you tell us what you want to have happen compared to what actually happens.  Because to me, it looks like it's working correctly.

Comment: Neither of those will match, because you are looking for the whole string of `evtsummary` inside one of your smaller strings.

Comment: I just want the result to be true.

Comment: `any(evtsummary.find(s) != -1 for s in ignore)`

Comment: The only way you could get the results you're claiming would be something like `any(s in evtsummary.split() for s in ignore)`, which (a) is very different from the code you showed us, and (b) the answer in that case would just be "don't do that". Please give us an example that actually demonstrates your problem; see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance.

Comment: You just want what result to be true?  Try using your words in the question.  Pretend we have no idea what you want before you start typing.

Comment: See if the way I have rewritten your question actually says what you should have said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mean:

```
if any(s in evtsummary for s in ignore):
    ...
```

which means, does `evtsummary` contain any item in the `ignore` list?

Comment: This works! thank you for the help, can you share the difference between your string and what I had?

Comment: It is the difference between "does `s` contain `evtsummary`", which is what you had, and "does `evtsummary` contain `s`" which is what you said you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'd upvote you, but it looks like I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 1):

assume `evtsummary` is your string as you say and you want to match `something 8002` and not `something8002`.

so just split `evtsummary` and then check :

```
if any(s in evtsummary.split() for s in ignore):
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am trying to match "8002" to the string "something8002, but it does not work. However, it will match to "something 8002"

Comment: is my interpreting upside down ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear what you actually want.  Here are three different things to try, each tested against three different strings.

```
ignore = ['40015','8002']

for evtsummary in ["something 8002", "something8002", "8002"]:
    print "trying with {}".format(evtsummary)
    if any(evtsummary in s for s in ignore):
        print "first"

    if any(s in evtsummary for s in ignore):
        print "second"

    if any(s in evtsummary.split() for s in ignore):
        print "third"
    print
```

It seems like you want the second option, but the original question sounded more like you wanted the third.

Comment: My mistake, I was looking for the second option like you pointed out.